# Trying to Connect different computers database . Throws Access denied for user 'root'@'DEV106' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect with my different computer mySQL db using following code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/test","root","pass");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from demo");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }

}
```

Note : my all computer are connected eith LAN architecture and also gives all the permission in between those computer, Certainly i don't know what could be issue if someone can help me out.

Comment: Try doing a telnet from the system running the application to the system where database is running . ex. telnet <address of db host>:<port>.

Comment: also you need to update mysql's configuration file for access it from more than one host likewise, i did it in past for the same requerement. you code looks good

Comment: how did you give permission to other computers?

Comment: @LahiruAshan i grant all permission to database with GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO 'monty'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; and added my computer->contro pan->remote->add

Comment: Thanks ALL. It works now after removing :3306